# QWebEngineView runJavaScript executed repeatedly

Tags: qt, qwebengineview

I am trying to implement the displaying of a web page in Qt.I add one buttoon ,when clicked,update the new html content,and Re-execution the js,but  when clicked 2 times,**Popup execute  2 times,when clicked 3 times,Popup execute  3 times**, I think, **it add js to the html content many times**. what should i do make the Popup execute  1 times?
[**I want to clear previous html content when click the button.but i don't know how to do** ]

in .h .
QWebEngineView *articleWebView;

in .cpp:
articleWebView =  new QWebEngineView();

in js.
function abs() {alert("test");}

QString articleJS = readArticleJs ();

```
QString funcStr =  QString("\n abs(\"%1 \",\"%2\");").arg(highlightWords1).arg(highlightSentece1);
articleJS.append (funcStr);
this->articleWebView->page ()->runJavaScript (articleJS);
```

Comment: It's unclear from the code you posted but probably upon the button click you repeatedly create new `QWebEngineViews` without removing the old ones.

Comment: in .cpp
void ReadingQuestionAndArticleMainWindow::getclickNextSignalFromRMtoolMain()
{
articleWebView->setHtml ("test");
connect(this->articleWebView, &QWebEngineView::loadFinished,[=](){
setAticleDataWithQuestion();
});

}

void ReadingQuestionAndArticleMainWindow::setAticleDataWithQuestion {
qDebug()<<"====Test======";
QString articleJS = "abs()";
this->articleWebView->page ()->runJavaScript (articleJS );
}

connect (this->readingTool,&RMtoolMain::toReadingQuestionAndArticleMainWindowSignalClickNext,this,&ReadingQuestionAndArticleMainWindow::getclickNextSignalFromRMtoolMain);

Comment: You should put this code into the question because within the comment it's really hard to read - there's no formatting or anything. But I managed to find out that you call `connect` each time `ReadingQuestionAndArticleMainWindow::getclickNextSignalFromRMtoolMain` runs. That explains the issue you observe - the connection to lambda is not a single-shot one, you don't need to re-establish it every time. Per current code each time the button is pressed you add more and more lambdas listening to the signal - that's why you get popup multiple times. You really need to connect the lambda only once.